# Content cannot be displayed: pba__Bedrooms_pb__c does not belong to SObject type pba__Listing__c

Tags: visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

I have the following controller and VF page. The code seems to be fine as I don't get any error but when I include the VF page in to an object I get this error:

Content cannot be displayed: pba__Bedrooms_pb__c does not belong to SObject type pba__Listing__c

This is my controller:

```
    public class TestGetPropertiesApexController {
    private final pba__Listing__c  prop;

    public Boolean getIsClassic() {
    return (UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme3' && ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('beLightning') == null);
}


    public TestGetPropertiesApexController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            stdController.addFields(new List<String>{'pba__Bedrooms_pb__c ', 'pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c ', 'pba__ListingPrice_pb__c ', 'PropertyOwnerContact__c  ', 'pba__Status__c '});
        }
        this.prop = (pba__Listing__c )stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public List<pba__Listing__c > getProperties () {             
        List<pba__Listing__c > properties = [
            SELECT Id, Name, pba__Bedrooms_pb__c, pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c, pba__ListingPrice_pb__c, PropertyOwnerContact__c , pba__Status__c FROM pba__Listing__c  WHERE Id != :prop.Id AND pba__Bedrooms_pb__c = :prop.pba__Bedrooms_pb__c
        ];
        return properties;
    }
}
```

This is my VF page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="pba__Listing__c" extensions="TestGetPropertiesApexController" standardStylesheets="{!isClassic}" applyBodyTag="{!isClassic}">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isClassic}">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! properties }" var="ct" id="leads_list">
                <apex:column value="{! ct.name}" />
                <apex:column value="{! ct.pba__Bedrooms_pb__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{! ct.pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{! ct.PropertyOwnerContact__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{! ct.pba__ListingPrice_pb__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{! ct.pba__Status__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! !isClassic}">
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <apex:slds />
        <div class="slds-scope">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer" id="leads_list">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Beds">Beds</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Baths">Baths</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Price">Price</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat value="{! properties }" var="ct">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" data-label="Name">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">
                                    <apex:outputLink value="/{! ct.Id}">{! ct.name }</apex:outputLink>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <td data-label="Beds">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{! ct.pba__Bedrooms_pb__c }">{! ct.pba__Bedrooms_pb__c }</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Baths">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{! ct.pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c }">{! ct.pba__FullBathrooms_pb__c }</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Price">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{! ct.pba__ListingPrice_pb__c }">{! ct.pba__ListingPrice_pb__c }</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Status">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{! ct.pba__Status__c }">{! ct.pba__Status__c }</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is caused by not having properly defined your controller extension as extending the `pba__Listing__c` by getting a `pba__Listing__c` record to reference in the Standard Controller in both the controller extension and the page.

I don't see a reference to an `pba__Listing__c` record variable named `prop` on your visualforce page like you've referenced in your controller extension. Further, in your controller, you've declared `prop` as private, which potentially could cause issues for you as well if you're going to get it from the page. I could be mistaken, but I don't believe you can have a public get on a private variable. I know you can't have a public set on one.

Comment: You surely can have a public getter on a private variable. `private final String someProperty; public String getSomeProperty() { return someProperty; }`